# Do Smoke Alarms have timers in them?

Tags: electrical, smoke-detectors, circuit

In my old residence, we had a smoke alarm that would always go off at 7 AM every Sunday. But whenever the power would go out it would go out at another random time, the first time was 3 PM every Saturday. Then the next time the power went out it went on 9 PM on Tuesday. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Was there something else that happened at 7PM on Sundays? And was it actually alarming, or just chirping/beeping?

Comment: Well when we first moved we just heard the noise, but after I started to investigate every week i figured out it was just the alarm making the beeping. Sounded kinda like it does when batteries are low.

Comment: Does it still chirp at you with a fresh battery installed?

Comment: It does actually, yes

Comment: How old is this smoke alarm?

Comment: About 10 to 15 years I believe

Comment: Is it a single chirp, or like a double chirp? Can you get us make and model info?

Comment: It's a double chirp, I get what you're trying to do here, and I'll get on that other info, im just not 100% sure why it only happened on Sundays at 7

Answer (score 1):

### Replace the smoke alarm

A "double chirp" from a smoke alarm these days is indicative that the smoke alarm has failed internal self-testing (chamber checks) and thus needs to be replaced outright.

Comment: Thank you, me and my wife will look to replace it tommorow. I'm still just not sure why it went at the same time each Sunday though.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the NFPA recommends replacing all smoke alarms every ten years.

Comment: Ok we just bought a new one, thank you. I'm still not sure why it beeped every 168 hours though.

Comment: @HuCooper -- without knowing the make and model, I wouldn't know why it'd use that interval for chamber checks

Comment: I totally get that and I'm gonna try to get that info, but you are saying that it is possible for something like this to happen?

Comment: @HuCooper -- yeah, I know at least some (many?) new smoke alarms will check their sensing chambers electrically as a form of periodic self-test and report this "double chirp" if that test fails

Comment: So I apologize, as it went off today I realized it was actually a single chirp, my mistake. It was another alarm we have, well had as we're replacing it today, that made the double chirp, i was confusing them, I apologize. This one is about 15 to 20 years old though, so I don't know if it would work like that. And as another comment suggested, we will be replacing it with a newer one soon.

Comment: FYI: according to the user manual for the Kidde detectors in my house, the "end of life" chirp is controlled strictly by a timer. It doesn't explain what effect, if any, having the detector unpowered has on the total time. Probably the timer is a "time in service", and unpowered time is not counted toward that. In any case, the docs say that the chirp starts after the detector has been in service for 10 years. It's possible to "snooze" the alarm some number of times, but eventually it will just keep chirping. No self-test is mentioned at all in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a house alarm system that these alarms are hooked to?
If so, it's a function of the system.

I have an older Moose alarm system that power cycles the smoke detectors every 24 hours as a functional test.
Some detectors will chirp when that happens.

If you lose house power sufficiently long that the alarm system loses power (battery runs down), then the 24 hour cycle will move depending on when power is restored.

Comment: Anyone vacuuming around that time on Sunday? Excessive dust can cause those to things to go off....fires in the fireplace? Although I suspect you probably just had an old alarm...